# How to force a related entry to appear in the bibliography with biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

I want to cite an entry related to another entry such that the child entry appears in the bibliography.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{kullback:related}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

### Constraints

In the above MWE:

- both `kullback:related` and `kullback` must appear in the bibliography unless explicitly skipped using the `skipbib` option.
- `kullback` must not necessarily be cited independently.
- must be able to have `mincrossrefs>1`.
- ideally only one pass of `biber` and `latex`.

### Methods I've tried

- use a custom `myref` field to point to the child entry and add an explicit `\nocite{\thefield{myref}}` within a custom driver. This works but has two undesirable side effects:

  1. It requires an extra pass of `biber` and `latex`.
  2. It does not work with the current dev version of `biblatex` (See [issue #407](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/407)).
- using `xref` with the `\entrydata` macro and `mincrossrefs=1`. This works, but I need it to work with `mincrossrefs>1`.

### A possible way forward

Explain to me how the `xref` field works such that I can modify it (or my custom `myref` field) to be included regardless of the value of `mincrossrefs`. The `crossref` field must continue to respect the value of `mincrossrefs` as outlined in the `biblatex` manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the latest biblatex 3.4 and biber 2.5 from Sourceforge. `minxrefs` is now a separate option when using `biber` - this was something planned a while ago but for some reason never implemented. The biblatex macros were already in place but `biber` needed some changes. These options are part of the backend functionality and so with the `bibtex` backend, `mincrossrefs` still controls xrefs too. There cannot be a separate option for this with `bibtex` as there is no such option for the `bibtex` program (since it's a `biblatex` concept).

Comment: As noted in my comment in issue #407, this is good! But it fails my first constraint if the skipbib option is set in kullback:related. This is only apparent in verbose styles. I've amended my MWE.

Comment: Can you add the bib entries to the MWE to make it really "W"?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with skipbib - it's a fairly complex interaction of things which I think are fixed now in the the latest 3.4/2.5.

Answer (score 1):

An additional useful piece of information which directly answers the question (although not with all constraints).

You can force a related entry to appear in a bibliography by overriding the `relatedoptions` field. e.g., `relatedoptions = {dataonly,skipbib=false}`.